# Get result of long-lived Livecycle process

Tags: web-services, livecycle

I am using .Net to make a web-service call to a livecycle long lived service. I cannot figure out how to get the resulting output from this service, as all I get back from my invoke_async call is a jobId.

I know I can use the JobManagerService to ping the job to see when it has completed, but I don't know how to get the output from the service call.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please be more specific. What's a JobManagerService? What is "livecycle"? Did you mean "lifecycle"? What technology are you using? Java? .NET?

Comment: Adobe Livecycle. This is a product from Adobe used to construct and distribute PDF documents.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same.  The job id is all that is returned from the invocation of a LiveCycle with invoke_async.  You can write a short-lived process in Workbench to do a SQL lookup to use the Job ID to reach over to other tables and get process information.  The table tb_job_instance has a field public_id that matches long_lived_invocation_id in tb_process_instance, so you can pass as input the job id you obtain into your new short-lived process to get the process id and from there do more lookups.